# Docker in a Parallels' Virtual Windows 10 Pro Machine

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, hyper-v, parallels

- I have a 2013 Mac Pro running the latest Parallels Desktop Pro v
  12.2.0 (41591)
- On it, is a Windows 10 Pro virtual with Docker Version 17.03.1-ce-win10 (11972)

Docker can only run with 'windows containers' because when trying to fire up the 'MobyLinux' instance in Hyper-V, it never fires up always bombing at:

***tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed***
I understand this to be some time dependent sync that has to happen at boot time or such failure occurs. I bought a WD 1TB SSD on a Thunderbolt dock to speed up the run/boot time of the virtual. (it was on my platter RAID cage before) to no avail. No diff.

Parallels IS set to '**enable nested virtualization**' and I have started a virtual in Hyper-V on the win 10 Pro VM just fine, no errors. I have checked and unchecked 'PMU Virtualization' which I understand will provide statistics to the host but slow the VM.

I tried:

- reducing the number of assigned cores to the VM as suggested by
  another post to no avail (2-6 cores tried)
- Reducing the cores to '1' for Docker (and mixing with above attempt)
- increasing the number of cores to docker
- adding/reducing memory to VM/Docker
- playing with the

  C:\Program
     Files\Docker\Docker\resources\MobyLinux.ps1

  file that loads the VM whereas in another post I changed something to
- verifying that "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx" is teh correct location for the .vhdx
- verifying that the .iso is at "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\mobylinux.iso"
- uninstalling Hyper-v/reinstalling Hyper-v manually and letting Docker do it automatically
  ...

I am at wit's end. I specifically bought this machine so I could do my MS/Visual Studio development along with iOS development on the same box. I have done so, this way, for the past 5-6 years with a 2009 Mac Pro before and now my 2013 MP, ***but never with Docker before***...

So, I need one of two solutions:

1. a way to make Visual Studio 2015/2017 'look' at my host Mac's Docker instance in order to debug/move on to development
2. a way to make this 'MobyLinux' Docker vm run.

Comment: Bumping into the same issues. Now, about 8 months further on, the issues remain.

Comment: I haven't tried to continue in Parallels. Their support had no answers. I got a native Windows Laptop with VS 2017 and RDP into it for Docker stuff for now.

Comment: I would like to note that the option 'enable nested virtualization' is now moved to the Paralells Desktop PRO version. This company is very keen on trying to extract more money from you. Very aggressive.

Comment: I have the PRO version...still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues and I had initially set the memory to the highest levels allotted and Docker just flat would not run in the Windows box. After tinkering with it for a while I realized that in the Windows box I had not done any of the updates so I ran all those and logged back in, and was getting the same issues of docker not running. That is when I moved over to Parallels and made the changes shown below. Hopefully that helps!

result of docker version:
https://a.cl.ly/kpumLPz4

hyper v:
https://a.cl.ly/jkunldkm

settings in parallels:
https://a.cl.ly/QwuGKq1D

additional settings in parallels that I changed:
https://a.cl.ly/9ZuNElnb

command that I ran for hello_world:
`docker run --rm busybox echo hello_world`

[windows docs on Linux containers 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux)

[docker docs on windows install](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)